# Add multiple products to cart - Magento

Tags: magento, addition, cart, product

I try to use that http://sourceforge.net/projects/massaddtocart/

It is exactly what I want, but it shows this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setProduct() on a non-object in [...]/app/code/local/BD83/MassAddToCart/Helper/Data.php on line 20
```

I want to to add multiple simple products with different qty to cart by one click. this option does not exist in Magento.

Any help is appreciated.

OK Jonathan, that is:

```
public function getButtonHtml(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    if ($product->getId() && !$product->getIsComposite()) {
        $qtyBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('bd83.massaddtocart.catalog.product.list.item.button');
        $qtyBlock->setProduct($product) // **LINE 20**
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setMinQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MIN_QTY))
            ->setDefaultQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_QTY))
            ->setMaxQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MAX_QTY));
        return $qtyBlock->toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

some exemples for what I want to get:
http://www.dickblick.com/products/winsor-and-newton-artists-acrylics/
http://www.polymexint.com/nouvelle-montana-black-blk-400ml.html

@Oliver: checking your response

Comment: paste in the contents of /app/code/local/BD83/MassAddToCart/Helper/Data.php around line 20 so that we can see some context please

Comment: thanks for quick response, that is the code :
public function getButtonHtml(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
    {
        if ($product->getId() && !$product->getIsComposite()) {
            $qtyBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()
->getBlock('bd83.massaddtocart.catalog.product.list.item.button');
 $qtyBlock->setProduct($product)
->setProductId($product->getId())
->setMinQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MIN_QTY))
->setDefaultQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_QTY))
->setMaxQty(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MAX_QTY));
return $qtyBlock->toHtml();
}
  return '';
 }

Comment: please edit your the question with the code and format it so that it's readable :) and mark which is line 20.  thx

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6185229/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 4):

still searching? Found this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9797

Seems to work in current versions, though I haven't tested it yet. If you solved it, at least future searchers will know where to find it!

/***EDIT****/

Well, to "not be considered a poor answer", this how you should implement the solution. None of the code is my work, creds to Uni-Man, Nexus Rex and the Magento Forum guys :)

The code is well documented. It creates a fullworthy Magento extension in the namespace "Company" with the name "Module".

First, implement the helper in app/code/local/Company/Module/helper/Data.php:

```
    <?php
    class Company_Module_Helper_Multiple extends Mage_Core_Helper_Url
    {
        /**
         * Return url to add multiple items to the cart
         * @return  url
         */
        public function getAddToCartUrl()
        {
            if ($currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')) {
                $continueShoppingUrl = $currentCategory->getUrl();
            } else {
                $continueShoppingUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true));
            }

            $params = array(
                Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($continueShoppingUrl)
            );

            if ($this->_getRequest()->getModuleName() == 'checkout'
                && $this->_getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'cart') {
                $params['in_cart'] = 1;
            }
            return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple', $params);
        }
    }
```

Next, you will need to do some template-changes. Copy the file app/design/base/default/templates/catalog/list.phtml to app/design/default/default/templates/catalog/list.phtml. This makes sure that, once the extension is no longer wanted, you/your client can go back to the normal list view without coding.
Modify the new list.phtml file as follows:

After

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
```

add

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->helper( 'Module/multiple' )->getAddToCartUrl() ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
<button class="form-button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

(This will open the form; all following items will add input boxes for quantity, so you can put all items in the cart using one sole button. This is put here, too.)

Scrolling down, you will find the area where normally the "Add To Cart" button is generated:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
```

Replace the content of the if-block with:

```
<fieldset class="add-to-cart-box">
  <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
  <legend><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></legend>
  <span class="qty-box"><label for="qty<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
  <input name="qty<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" maxlength="12" value="" /></span>
</fieldset>
```

This is the input-field for the quantity.
To close the -tag, insert after

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

at the bottom:

```
<button class="form-button" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add Items to Cart') ?></span></button>
</form>
```

What you do here is:
- generate a second "Add To cart"-Button, identical with the one on top
- close the form

When an item ist added to the cart, normally Magento will call the Checkout_CartController. We have to modify this one in order to add not just one, but all items to the cart in the deserved quantity.

Therefore, add the file app/code/local/Company/Module/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php and fill in this:

```
> require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
> 
> class Company_Module_Checkout_CartController extends
> Mage_Checkout_CartController {

>     public function addmultipleAction()
>     {
>         $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products');
>         if (!is_array($productIds)) {
>             $this->_goBack();
>             return;
>         }
> 
>         foreach( $productIds as $productId) {
>             try {
>                 $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty' . $productId, 0);
>                 if ($qty <= 0) continue; // nothing to add
>                 
>                 $cart = $this->_getCart();
>                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
>                     ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
>                     ->load($productId)
>                     ->setConfiguredAttributes($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute'))
>                     ->setGroupedProducts($this->getRequest()->getParam('super_group', array()));
>                 $eventArgs = array(
>                     'product' => $product,
>                     'qty' => $qty,
>                     'additional_ids' => array(),
>                     'request' => $this->getRequest(),
>                     'response' => $this->getResponse(),
>                 );
>     
>                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_before_add', $eventArgs);
>     
>                 $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
>     
>                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_after_add', $eventArgs);
>     
>                 $cart->save();
>     
>                 Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
>     
>                 $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());    
>                 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);
>             }
>             catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
>                 if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
>                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($product->getName() . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception $e) {
>                 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Can not add item to shopping cart'));
>             }
>         }
>         $this->_goBack();
>     } }
```

We are overriding the existing Mage Core class with our own, resulting in the use of our controller for this purpose.

You will also have to add the module's config.xml as usual in app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Company_Module>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Company_Module>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <rewrite>
                <company_module_checkout_cart>
                    <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/addmultiple/.*$#]]></from>
                    <to>/module/checkout_cart/addmultiple/</to>
                </company_module_checkout_cart> 
            </rewrite>
            <helpers>
                <Module>
                    <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
                </Module>
            </helpers>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <company_module>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Company_Module</module>
                        <frontName>module</frontName>
                    </args>
                </company_module>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

What this does:
- replaces call to cart controller with call to own multiadd controller
- registers helper
- applies router to frontend

Please tell me if more documentation on this is needed.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this with jQuery/Javascript.  All products on the page are in `<li>` tags.  These tags have an attribute called `data-product-id` which contain the numeric ID of each product.  Also, I'm sure you know that you can add multiple products to a shopping cart using a URL such as `http://www.yoursite.com/checkout/cart/add?product=1&related_product=2,3`  (Replace the numbers 1,2 and 3 with your own product ID's.)

Knowing this if you have a page of products we can use jQuery/JavaScript to generate a URL that gets all the product ID's for each product on the page, and place them accordingly within a URL like the above.

To accomplish this, first, make sure you have jQuery added to your site:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Now, add the following script - there are notes to let you know what each variable and function does:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//Function to get all product ID's, & create a URL that will add all the items
function generateUrl() {
    //the variable 'firstItem' will find the first Product ID in an li tag
    var firstItem = $("li").first().attr("data-product-id");
    //the variable 'otherItem' will earch all other li's, and grab their product ID's
    var otherItem = $('li').nextAll().map(function() {return $(this).attr('data-product-id');}).get();
    //the newURL creates the URL that adds the products to the cart; replace the site URL with your own.
    var newUrl = 'http://shop.yoursite.com/checkout/cart/add?product=' + firstItem + '&related_product=' + otherItem;
    //this seeks a link with the ID of "productlink", then will add the URL generated from newURL to the href tag
    $('#productlink').attr("href" , newUrl);
}
//start function!
generateUrl();

});

</script>
```

Now, create a link with the id of productlink.

```
<a href="" id="productlink">Add All Items To Cart</a>
```

That's it!